# Principal square root of a product of complex numbers with positive real part

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Given $n$ complex numbers $z_i$ with $\Re z_i>0$, why is it that $$\prod_i\sqrt{z_i}=\sqrt{\prod_i z_i}?$$Numerically, this appears to be the case, however, I don't see an easy way to prove it.

Comment: Which branch of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ are you using? Anyway, I think this is untrue for any branch. For example, if we use a branch that gives the usual square root function on the positive real axis and has a branch cut in the second or third quadrant, and take $z_1 = \cdots = z_n = \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}\right)$, $n > 2$, then the left-hand side is $-1$ but the right-hand side is $1$.

Comment: It isn't the case.

Comment: I have a branch cut on the negative real axis.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My choice of examples was poor.

Comment: It *is* true for $n = 2$ and the branch of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ that coincides with the usual definition on the positive real numbers and has branch cut along the negative real axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true.

If your branch is defined over all $z$, with $\Re z>0$, but IT IS NOT defined at 
$$
z_0=r\,\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}, \quad \vartheta\in (\pi/2,3\pi/2),
$$
then $w=r^{1/3}\,\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta/3}$ has positive real part, and your branch is not defined on $z_0=w\cdot w\cdot w$.